# Q: SignalR authentication with .NET client works locally but not on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, signalr, credentials

I'm hosting my signalR in IIS, and I have a .net client that resides in the same website. I'm using windows authentication so credentials are set this way:

```
hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

This all work when I run the site locally, but it would give me a 401 error when deployed on a server:

```
SignalR: myhub.DoStuff failed to execute. Error: StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
  WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Date: Thu, 20 Apr 2017 19:40:41 GMT
  Content-Length: 1293
  Content-Type: text/html
}
```

I see the above error in the browser developer tool and it happens when this line is run:

```
hubConnection.Start().Wait();
```

I'm pretty sure the credential itself is right, because when I run the site locally, and put in the hub url that's deployed on the server, and pass in a credential for that server, I am able to start the hubConnection.

So what could be something that's preventing the SignalR .Net client from authenticating on a server, but not locally?

Answer (score 0):

Now I am leaning towards the theory that the credential passed to the .NET client of SignalR doesn't have enough rights. Basically every time I get the 401 error, I can see a new Audit Failure entry popping up in the server's event viewer log, saying the credential that was used couldn't log on.

Does anyone know what rights need to be granted to the account?